# How to update SSH passphrase in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I copy-pasted a wrong SSH passphrase when prompted for it in VSCODE and it was saved because the "save" checkbox was checked. Now I cannot sync to Github.

Is there a way to update the wrong passphrase in VSCODE? I searched settings and googled but could not find a way.

This is the git log

```
> git pull --tags origin master
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Edit:
I can commit if I switch from SSH to HTTPS following instructions from  https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories. But I cannot commit if I switch again from HTTPS to SSH.

Answer (score 0):

It was probably not VSCode that asked for a password but your authentification agent. Try `ssh-add -D` in a terminal. `ssh-add -l` will list "remembered" keys.

Comment: `ssh-add -D` returns
`All identities removed.`. `ssh-add -l` returns `The agent has no identities.`. Still can't commit and the git log shows same output

Comment: So, does VSCode work now?

Comment: No. Still can't commit and the git log shows same output in first post

Comment: try this in a VSCode built-in terminal

Comment: Yes I did that and got the same results. When I click `Sync Changes` under source control I get the same git log saying permission denied.

Comment: I am not aware of any such feature in VSCode, but if it is indeed the case - maybe it is an extension doing this - the password can be either in `~/.vscode` or in `${workspaceFolder}/.vscode`. In any case, if an extension is doing this, I think you should report the security risks involved to its author.

Comment: It was a popup window in vscode that has not appeared since. I'm not sure if it was an extension. As a precaution, I have deleted the SSH key and will use https to commit.